# Ajax Post Request is inconsistent, why?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, servlets

I have a simple login form, which checks credentials through a post request.

 Problem is it doesn't work every time.
Following is the code I'm using to check credentials:

```
function login() {
  alert('asdf');
  $.post("login",
         {
    email: document.getElementById('email').value,
    pwd: document.getElementById('pwd').value
  },
         function (data, status) {
    alert(status);
    window.location.replace("message.jsp?type=login" + data);
  });
}
```

I tried alerts to debug the problem and noticed that the first alert gets executed every time but the alert inside the post function doesnt get executed every time. 
And when ever the alert for status is not executed, the url on the browser changes to:

http://localhost:8080/project_name/index.jsp?email=my_email_address&password=my_password

Please Note: The Parameter name I specified in Post request was pwd for password textfield, but its password here

My Login form:

```
<form onSubmit='login()'>
    <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" required>
    <input id="pwd" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" required>
    <button type="submit"> Login </button>
</form>
```

Servlet Returns 0 or 1 if login is successfull and message.jsp print a small message accordingly

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, having a button type submit or input type submit in a form overrides the onSubmit attribute.